# What does "architectural" really mean when used to describe building products?

Tags: terminology

Various types of building-related materials and products are often described as being "architectural". I have seen windows, doors, roofing tiles, etc. all described this way.

- [Example 1](http://www.kawneer.com/kawneer/north_america/en/product.asp?cat_id=1907&prod_id=4468&desc=ultra-thermal-architectural-windows)
- [Example 2](http://www.certainteed.com/residential-roofing/what-are-architectural-roofing-shingles/)
- [Example 3](https://www.andersenwindows.com/products/series/architectural-collection/)

One possibility is that this is just meaningless marketing gobbledygook meant to convey an impression of high quality.

Or it might have real meaning, but not necessarily a consistent meaning in all cases.

But if there is a real, meaningful definition that would help navigate through myraid product choices - what is it?

Thanks

Comment: ....we are going to mark this one up 900% and laugh all the way to the bank.

Comment: @Ecnerwal so you agree with my first hypothesis then :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not have a consistent meaning, but in the context of building materials/products is usually intended to suggest a higher level of quality or prestige. I think this comes from the suggestion that this particular material might be specified by an architect, who wants a quality project and doesn't care much about price. In contrast, builder-grade products are low-quality, low-price, generally acceptable items available at low cost for builders who want to limit expenses.

In some areas a more specific meaning has evolved - the shingles you point out are an example, where architectural shingles are a class with a typical design (in contrast to cheaper 3-tab shingles).

Answer (score 1):

Your second link has a good working example,

> Architectural roofing shingles provide stunning three-dimensional appearance.

`Architectural` is being used in the context of someone saying,

> Oh @DaveInCaz the architecture in this neighborhood is so quaint!

I believe a related term might be `functional`. This would be used in the context of:

> @DaveInCaz those cabinets look ugly but they're functional. They are well organized and durable.